# Need help creating shortcuts on the desktop in ubuntu

Tags: shortcuts

Just wondering how do I add desktop shortcuts in Ubuntu. I know I cannot right click and add (like Windows or Linux Mint).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**"Make Link"** is what you are looking for. Right-click on file/folder from nautilus and click on 'Make Link'. Which will creates symbolic links then you can **move link to desktop**.

**Nautilus:**

[image]

---

**Thunar** file-manager has inbuilt such facilities:-

To install thunar type following command: (make sure enable main repository and `sudo apt-get update`):

```
sudo apt-get install thunar
```

[image]

---

Using **command-line**(terminal):

You can create symbolic link using **`ln`** command as follows:

```
ln -s "<Source>" "<Target>"
```

Example:

```
ln -s /media/pandya/Ext4/14.04_Trusty-Tahr/Pkgs  ~/Desktop
```

where `/media/pandya/Ext4/14.04_Trusty-Tahr/Pkgs` is source and `~/Desktop` is target

Visit **`man ls`** for more details.

---

For creating **launcher** install `sudo apt-get install gnome-panel` and refer to: [This Q/A](https://askubuntu.com/a/66918/256099).

Answer (score 1):

Answer could be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Open your favourite text editor, like Gedit or nano, and type in (copy and paste):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=x.y
Name=ProgramName
Comment=This is my comment
Exec=/home/alex/Documents/exec.sh
Icon=/home/alex/Pictures/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Ofcourse, edit the entries to match your program.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder /usr/share/applications and find the program you want.
Then right click on it and copy.
Now go to your home folder and open up the folder Desktop.
Right click and then select paste.

Comment: Oh my, that was quick. Thanks so much!!!!! Have a good day

Comment: This is not really a desktop shortcut. This will be another instance of the program.

Comment: @DanJohansen Just for the record; your comment is totally incorrect. Files in `/usr/share/applications` *are* `.desktop` files. They won't work however as a starter on your desktop unless they are made executable (most of them are not in `/usr/share/applications`)

Comment: @JacobVlijm ah sorry. Got it confused with the regular applications folder. :)